# Number of fake rocks

Tags: combinatorics

We have $2n$ rocks, some of them are "fake", in other words, heavy. We have a balance scale.All heavy rocks have the same weight, such as light ones.
We want to find minimum number of weights for deciding which ones are fake.

If with $s(n)$ we denote  the minimum number of  weights, and suppose that there are  $k$ fake rocks, then it is obvious that $s(n)\geq \log_3\left(C_{2n}^{k}\right)$. Please help to prove that $s(n)\leq \log_3\left(C_{2n}^{k}\right)$ or show me a way , how can I find the minimum number.

Comment: Please help in what???

Comment: I have  edited it

Comment: OK, so "help" means you must have tried something and couldn't get it done; can you please share your preliminary findings, and the exact difficulty that you have encountered?

Comment: What you're asking for would imply $s(n)$ is exactly equal to $\log_3(C_{2n}^k)$.  But $\log_3(C_{2n}^k)$ is, in general, not an integer.

Comment: yes , you are right, I'll correct it.

Comment: Except you didn't.

Comment: In [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714165) you added in a comment that the two heavier rocks are the same weight. It makes a difference whether they are, and this piece of information is missing here.